# Diesel truck library

Tags: sound-effects

Anyone know of a good one? I have alot of heavy trucks to cut and im trying out AudioGaming's AudioMotors.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the peterbilt 379 from pole.se is pretty good you can check it out from their [shop](http://pole.se/sounds.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:

https://www.soundeffects.ch/surround-sound-effects-_e.php?soundeffects=truck+diesel&soundcategory=&type=

and

https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundeffects/sound-effects-categories/sound-effects-truck.php

If you are interested in trucks only, I can arrange a individual truck-bundle for you. Also with unpublished sounds which are not on the site. Contact me by mail, you will find it at my site.

Best

Guido